# How to get link of file to download with wget

Tags: wget

I am using Ubuntu 19.10. For automation purposes, I need to download this file with a script.

But I am not able to get the link.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the link using the console. Open it with the right click -> *examine element* -> *terminal* (or *console*, don't know how it is in english), and just do like you had done in your gif.

Here is your link : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/user-themegnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com.v38.shell-extension.zip

and screenshot of Firefox terminal for this link :

[image]

so your `wget` command would be :

```
wget https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/user-themegnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com.v38.shell-extension.zip
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the `wget` command:

```
wget https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/user-themegnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com.v38.shell-extension.zip
```

- How to get the download link for Firefox:

  1. Click *Save* on the download window and select a download location. You can either save the file or cancel the download.
  2. Click the *Downloads* button on the Firefox toolbar and select *Show All Downloads*.
  3. *Right-click* on your downloaded (or cancelled) file and select *Copy Download Link*.
- How to get the download link for Chrome:

  1. Click *Save* on the download window and select a download location. You can either save the file or cancel the download.
  2. Click *Show all* on the downloads toolbar at the bottom of the browser.
  3. *Right-click* on your downloaded (or cancelled) file and select *Copy link address*.

Comment: not sure if it works for that particular web page, but this firefox  extension gets the links on a web page.
https://sites.google.com/site/linkgopher/

Comment: @pierrely By visiting the [extension's GitHub repository](https://github.com/az0/linkgopher/), I saw that it hasn't been updated for 2 years. Could you check if that still works? If yes, then you could add this option as an answer too. I would upvote that!

Comment: yep, linkgopher works for me with Firefox, 19.10 ubuntu. Installed through gnome tweaks through Firefox, probably . though I might not have as I cannot see it there ijn 'available' search.
github to source gets me this link
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/